# Angular 5 with polyfills.ts not good working in Safari: 'undefined' is not a function

Tags: angular, safari, polyfills

I run app: ng serve --aot

My angular.cli file have "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",

My polyfills.ts:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/promise';

import 'classlist.js';

import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'web-animations-js';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

import 'intl';

import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

My app workin in browsers: Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera, Mozilla, but not working in Safari.

Safari print information:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'i(d)')

How resolve this problem.

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: same boat here too.